# Image is not loading in push notification using FCM in android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am newbie to android and learning new things,I am working on FCM push notification,I want to implement Big picture style push notifications,I have implemented it successfully,even i am getting notification along with message but i am facing a problem that in push notification image is not loading,can anyone help me to figure it out?
my service is as below.

```
MyFirebaseMessagingServiceTemp extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    String store_id, img_url, msg;
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessageService";
    Bitmap bitmap;

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        /*
        There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
        here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
        traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
        is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
        When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
        and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
        messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

        */
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            JSONObject job = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
            img_url = job.optString("img_url");
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            msg = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody().toString();
        }

        //The message which i send will have keys named [message, image, AnotherActivity] and corresponding values.
        //You can change as per the requirement.

        //message will contain the Push Message
        // String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
        //imageUri will contain URL of the image to be displayed with Notification
        //  String imageUri = remoteMessage.getData().get("img_url");
        //If the key AnotherActivity has  value as True then when the user taps on notification, in the app AnotherActivity will be opened.
        //If the key AnotherActivity has  value as False then when the user taps on notification, in the app MainActivity will be opened.
        String TrueOrFlase = remoteMessage.getData().get("AnotherActivity");

        //To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
        bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(img_url);

        sendNotification(msg, bitmap);

    }


    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     */

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody, Bitmap image) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SlashActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//        intent.putExtra("AnotherActivity", TrueOrFalse);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Log.d("====message body===>", messageBody);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(image))/*Notification with Image*/
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    /*
    *To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
    * */
    public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return bitmap;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting image from URL here - bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(img_url);  ?????

Comment: yes,I am getting an image url,i can get image in browser well but not in notification.

Comment: can you share some screenshot or error log something...

Comment: follow this tutorial [Here](http://androidbash.com/firebase-push-notification-android/) may help you.